# Is there a way to access Vue $scopedSlot's mounted DOM element?

Tags: vue.js

I have a scoped slot named myElement, I can access it via `this.$scopedSlots.myElement()[0]`.

Usually when a vnode is mounted there is a `$el` containing the DOM element, but not in scoped slots apparently, there is only an undefined `elm`.

I also tried to put a ref on the slot in the child template and access it through `.context.$refs` but it lists the refs on the parent template only.

**Is there any way I can access that mounted DOM element, if its id or class is unknown from the child component?**

Thanks

---

### More Details:

Parent template (Pug)

```
child-component
  template(v-slot:myelement="{ on }")
    span My element content
```

Child component

```js
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.$scopedSlots.myelement()[0])
    // From here I want to get the position of the span with
    // span.getBoundingClientRect()
  }
```

---

### Reproduction link:

https://codepen.io/antoniandre/pen/BaogjrM?editable=true&editors=101

Comment: Where in code do you need access to the element? Are you rendering the scoped slot within a render function or the template? It would help if you can provide some sample code that illustrates what you're trying to do because the answer depends on your situation.

Comment: I have updated the question to give more details @DecadeMoon

Comment: This sound as if the slot didnt mount yet. Try to wait a rendercycle. await this.$nextTick()

Comment: I have tried that

Comment: here is a reproduction link: https://codepen.io/antoniandre/pen/BaogjrM?editable=true&editors=101

Comment: hmm is this intended? as a workaround you can grab `data.attrs.id` from the scoped slot and add an id `span(id="myelement") span with {{content}}.` then query `this.$el.getElementById(id)`

Comment: yeah, unfortunately this is in the context of a library where the span (in the parent) is on users full control so we can't modify it from the child :/

Comment: added another workaround, by adding an id to the slot component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only workaround that I've found so far is this:

First get the vnode of the scopedSlot, get its given context, crawl each vnode children of the context to find itself by the `_uid` key, which will contain the `$el` mounted element.
This is not very straightforward but it does the trick.

```js
mounted () {
    const { context } = this.$scopedSlots.activator()[0]
    console.log(context.$children.find(vnode => vnode._uid === this._uid).$el)
}
```

I asked in Vue forum and Vue chat but I am still looking for a better way, if there is let me know.

Answer (score 1):

So something like this can be used to workaround:

```
mounted () {
    const myEl = this.$scopedSlots.myelement()[0];
    if(myEl.data && myEl.data.attrs && myEl.data.attrs.id){
      const id = myEl.data.attrs.id    
      console.log([this.$el.querySelector('#id')])
    } else {
      throw new Error('slot myelement needs an id'); 
    }
  }
```

or forcefully apply an id:

```
const Child = {

  render: function(h){
    const myEl = this.$scopedSlots.myelement()[0]
    myEl.data = {attrs: {id: 'id'}};
    console.log(myEl)
    return h('div', {}, [myEl])
  },

  mounted () {
      console.log([this.$el.querySelector('#id')])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Estradiaz that's a good idea. But it will override the id that the user may have put in there. Appending a class and removing it could work though. I am still looking for a great way, otherwise I will choose this trick.

Comment: you can also check if it has an id already and use this or add some id otherwise^^